# Android Studio не видит ни один телефон

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня есть 2 компьютера, и на обоих стоит Android Studio (вчера установил). При этом на первом компьютере среда с самого начала видит любой телефон и загружает в него программы, а на втором компьютере не видно ни одного телефона.

`adb devices` так же не показывает телефоны.

Пробовал устанавливать новое sdk, установил google usb driver, установил в телефоне передачу PTP (прочитал на других сайтах), но это не помогло. Кабели и телефоны исправны, т. к. работает на другом компьютере. Значит, проблема либо в студии, либо в компе.

Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: P. S. режим разработчика конечно же включён

Comment: Проверить установку драйверов ADB. Диспетчер устройств в помощь.

Comment: Попробуй установить pdanet на телефон и пк

Answer (score 1):

Подключение неопознанных устройств.При этом только стоит догадываться, что ваши компьютеры работают под ОС Windows а на подключаемых устройствах включен режим разработчика и разрешена отладка по USB. Итак начнем:

1. Проверка наличия драйвера 
   Откройте Android SDK Manager. Найдите раздел Extras. Проверьте  наличие установленного у вас Google USB Driver. В случае если Google USB Driver у вас не установлен, поставьте галочку напротив Google USB Driver и нажмите Install Packages.
2. Редактирование  inf-файла

Внимание: перед редактированием inf-файла рекомендуется сделать его резервную копию.

2.1 В папке %android-sdk%\extras\google\ usb_driver  открываем файл android_winusb.inf  и ищем там строки:

;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01

2.2 Делаем копию этих строк, заменяем Google Nexus One на %имя_вашего_устройства% для его идентификации.

2.3 Открываем диспетчер устройств Windows. Ищем там наше устройство(Android, Android Composite ADB Interface и т.п.). Открываем свойства устройства, вкладка «Сведения», в списке выбираем пункт «ИД оборудования».
Копируем строчку, которая показана в примере на рисунке, и вставляем ее значения в копию строк скопированных в п.2.2 в редактируемом  inf-файл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

;TEXET TM-7025

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003&MI_01

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003

%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003&MI_01

В %SingleAdbInterface% удаляем лишнюю информацию,  в %CompositeAdbInterface% вставляем полностью.

2.4 Сохраняем отредактированный inf-файл.

3 Установка драйвера

В диспетчере устройств  удаляем все ранее установленные adb драйверы(если были). Обновляем список устройств и видим наше устройство без драйверов. Открываем его свойства и выбираем «Обновить драйверы», выбираем установку из папки, указываем папку с отредактированным inf-файлом и запускаем установку.

4 Проверка подключения

Переподключаем кабель с устройством. Ожидаем обнаружения устройства OS Windows. Открываем консоль( Win+R, вводим cmd) и пишем adb devices. Если все прошло хорошо — видим пункт списка, обозначающий, что утилита adb установила связь с устройством.

Если команда adb у вас вообще не работает. Компьютер -> Свойства -> Переменные среды. Ищем переменную Path и в конце дописываем (ни в коем случае не перезаписываем) в конце точку с запятой, а после адрес папки, где расположена утилита adb(обычно %android-sdk%\platform-tools). Перезагрузите OS Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого телефона еще нужно свой драйвер установить. Например,для LG я установил себе LGMobileDriver. Лезешь на офф.сайт компании, выпустившей твой телефон, и качаешь нужный драйвер. Должно помочь